# side effect about \renewbibmacro*{author} to show a shortauthor before author and title, and to add a word after the shortauthor

Tags: biblatex

I need something like this in the bibliography as well as the first appearance in citations

> 곽윤직 편집대표, 민법주해 제V권 제1판(민일영 집필부분), (박영사, 2011).

곽윤직 is a shortauthor, 편집대표 is a specific word, 민법주해 is a booktitle, 제V권 is a volume, 제1판 is an edition, 집필부분 is another specific word, 박영사 is a publisher, and 2011 is self-evident.

I achieved shortauthor part expression(곽윤직 편집대표) by below code. Other codes did the remaining part and those did nothing to do with my problem considering my test for making a minimal working example.

```
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
 \ifboolexpr{
  test \ifuseauthor
  and
  not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  and
  not test {\ifkeyword{kommentar}}
  }
  {\printnames{author}%
    \iffieldundef{authortype}
    {}
    {\setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}%
    \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}}
    {\printnames{shortauthor}\addspace\printtext{편집대표}
   \iffieldundef{authortype}
   {}
   {\setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}%
    \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}}}
```

But then, this caused the same author not to be replaced with a dash anymore in the bibliography like below.

> Hess, Stephen A., "Cardinal Change" Doctrine in Federal Contracts Law, American Law Reports
> Westlaw, 2006.
>
> Hess, Stephen A., "Total Cost Method(or Approach)" and "Modified Total Cost Method(or Approach)"
> to Proving Damages in Federal Contract Cases, American Law Reports Westlaw, 2005.

What I want is this, keeping the above shortauthor expression(곽윤직 편집대표 ...). (btw, don't bother about indent plz.)

> Hess, Stephen A., "Cardinal Change" Doctrine in Federal Contracts Law, American Law Reports
> Westlaw, 2006.
>
> _______, "Total Cost Method(or Approach)" and "Modified Total Cost Method(or Approach)"
> to Proving Damages in Federal Contract Cases, American Law Reports Westlaw, 2005.

My MWE is this.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
\defbibheading{bibliography}[bibliography]{\section*{#1}}

\usepackage{lipsum, filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
 @article{Hess2006,
       author = {Stephen A. Hess},
       title = {``Cardinal Change'' Doctrine in Federal Contracts Law},
       journaltitle = {American Law Reports},
       year = {2006},
   }
  @article{Hess2005,
       author = {Stephen A. Hess},
       title = {``Total Cost Method(or Approach)'' and ``Modified Total Cost Method(or Approach)'' to Proving Damages in Federal Contract Cases},
       journaltitle = {American Law Reports},
       year = {2005},
   }
   \end{filecontents}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
 \ifboolexpr{%
  test \ifuseauthor
  and
  not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
  {\printnames{author}%
    \iffieldundef{authortype}
    {}
    {\setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}%
    \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}}
    {\printnames{shortauthor}\addspace\printtext{test}%
   \iffieldundef{authortype}
   {}
   {\setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}%
    \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}
    }}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{\cite{Hess:2005aa}}

\lipsum[3]\footnote{\cite{Hess:2006aa}}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

By the way, even when I copy and paste the whole contents of `\newbibmacro*{author}` in biblatex.def, this thing happens. Changing the command to `\renewbibmacro` does the same.

MacTex Tex Live 2020, XeLaTeX applied. Bibliography style neutral in my test.

Comment: You need to base your modification on the `author` bibmacro in `authortitle.bbx` or `authoryear.bbx`, which supports the `dashed` option, and not on the generic `author` bibmacro from `biblatex.def`, which does not.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question, but might still be useful: `\footnote{\cite{Hess:2005aa}}` can usually be replaced by the shorter `\footcite{Hess:2005aa}`. If all (or the majority of) your citations are footnote citations, you can set the `biblatex` option `autocite=footnote,` and use `\autocite` instead of `\footcite`.

Comment: @moewe  thank you for such a fast answer. From your comment, I tried to modify author macro in `authortitle.bbx`. Because I'm quite a newbie to latex and biblatex, I've done trail and miss finally to find a fix. It would be ugly from the author's view, but it does work. Thank you. I replaced `@lasthash` with `\printnames{shortauthor}~text`